# ZSH multiline string behaviour with SELECT/FOR

Tags: string, zsh, substitution

I'm trying to understand what's happening with the string when the converting to a variable.

Eg.
With the substitution inline, the desired output occurs...

```
for CLOUD in $(jq -r '.clouds[].cloud_name' publicClouds.json)
do
 echo "> $CLOUD"
done

...
> google-us-east1
> azure-southcentralus
> google-us-west3
> aws-us-east-1
> azure-eastus
> azure-eastus2
> google-us-east4
> azure-westus2
> azure-westcentralus
```

But, if I move it to a variable, it becomes one string, regardless of quoting...

```
CLOUDS=$(jq -r '.clouds[].cloud_name' publicClouds.json)

for CLOUD in "$CLOUDS"
  do
  echo "> $CLOUD"
done

> aws-af-south-1
azure-south-africa-north
aws-me-south-1
aws-ap-east-1
azure-eastasia
google-asia-east2
```

Though variable line breaks appear preserved:

```
wc -l <<< $CLOUDS
103
```

However, this will work if I surround the variable too...

```
CLOUDS=($(jq -r '.clouds[].cloud_name' publicClouds.json))
for CLOUD in $CLOUDS
do
 echo "> $CLOUD"
done

> aws-af-south-1
> azure-south-africa-north
> aws-me-south-1
> aws-ap-east-1
> azure-eastasia
> google-asia-east2
> aws-ap-south-1
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Remove quotes from `for CLOUD in "$CLOUDS"`?

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) is very on-point.

Comment: ...in general, if you want to treat a multi-line string as an array, _transform it to an array_. `readarray -t clouds < <(jq -r '.clouds[].cloud_name' publicClouds.json)`, then you can `for cloud in "${clouds[@]}"; do`

Comment: Note that POSIX specifies that all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or operating-system-provided tools; names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application-defined use, and are what you should use for your own names.

Comment: To emphasize that using an array is not just a matter of stylistic choice but correctness, `for CLOUD in $CLOUDS` has subtle and not-so-subtle bugs; see what happens if you have a cloud named `* testing only *`

Comment: [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29) are also relevant.

Comment: That said, I wonder if you're actually using zsh and not bash. `CLOUDS=($(jq -r '.clouds[].cloud_name' publicClouds.json)); for CLOUD in $CLOUDS` **doesn't** work the way you describe in this question in bash: in bash, `$CLOUDS` refers only to `${CLOUDS[0]}`, so the for loop would ignore all but the first element.

Comment: ...if that _is_ the case (and it's by intent rather than accident), please remove "bash" from the tagging and title; bash and zsh are very different shells, not mutually compatible in either direction.

Comment: Ty folks. 

Yea, part of the naming that was going on here was being set as global variables for the shell, so we went with all caps and the environment had been changed to zsh, so I'll update that accordingly.

Comment: I thought the quoting was the issue somewhere, as I know that in some cases the line breaks are transformed, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. 

I agree that the the ideal path is a literal transformation to an array, but I was at a loss as to why the conversion to a variable was failing vs inline and it could be related to one of the pitfalls above. Ty @CharlesDuffy

Comment: globals-are-all-caps is convention in some other languages; but for the convention that applies in POSIX-compliant shells (which zsh isn't, so ignore this there), see the relevant standards document at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- read it keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable will update the value of any like-named environment variable (which incidentally means that 99% of the time when people write `export PATH=...`, the `export` is unnecessary).